# How to remove the title bar in mintty cygwin

Tags: terminal, cygwin

How do i remove the title bar in the cygwin mintty terminal window ? 
there is no option in the options -> window configuration

[image]

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only if you launch from a command line. Use `--Border` (alias `-B`) followed by either `void` or `frame`. For example...

```
mintty -B void
```

Per `man mintty` (which you should read) the difference is:

> Suppress window title, display only a frame or no border.

So `void` results in no border at all and `frame`, yep, just a frame.

You will have to use keyboard shortcuts to move the window around, of course.